# Is there a RESTful way to configure routes for habtm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes, has-and-belongs-to-many

In Rails you can use nested routes to create RESTful routes for has_one and has_many relationships. Examples can be found on the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rails.info/routing_outside_in.html#_nested_resources)

I'd like to ask if there is a good way to configure RESTful routes for habtm relationships? For example if I have a relationship A-habtm-B, my idea is to configure nested routes for A has_many B, and nested routes for B has_many A. Would that work? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since HABTM is a two way `has_many` association, your approach is correct and nested resources on both sides will work just fine. Other than that, I would reconsider using a `has_many :through` association instead of HABTM, since it's more versatile.